# Axios Error CanceledError when trying to forward POST request with Axios

Tags: javascript, express, next.js, axios, proxy

When trying to forward a POST request from an express backend to another backend with axios, I am receiving an axios error "CanceledError: Request stream has been aborted". This doesn't happen with GET requests. The other backend is through NextJS.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import express from 'express';
import { parse } from 'url';

DESTINATION_URL = ...

async function forwardRequest(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    const { path } = parse(req.url, true);
    const forwardUrl = DESTINATION_URL + path;
    await axios(forwardUrl, {
        method: req.method,
        data: req,
        responseType: 'stream',
    }).then((response) => {
        // Pipe data from destination response to res
        response.data.pipe(res);
    });
}

const ForwardRouter = express.Router();
ForwardRouter.all('*', forwardRequest);

export default ForwardRouter
```

I've tried changing the axios request to include the same headers as the function parameter's request, but this caused it to fail for all requests, including GET, with a different error. CORS is configured on the other backend with Access-Control-Allow-Origin as * and POST permitted.

Comment: perhaps it's because `data: req` causing issues, because that looks completely wrong, surely you'd want to "forward" the incoming body as the body. You could do some basic debugging by adding a `.catch` to see what the error is

Comment: @JaromandaX That was exactly it. I was adapting [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3971#issuecomment-1157753554) and didn't properly think through adapting it since it was a different protocol I assume. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from using `data: req` instead of `data: req.body` within the axios request.
Make sure to correct it when resolving the data.